# Do Google search results account for post DOM-loaded HTML/CSS/JavasScript adjustments?

Tags: jquery, html, css, seo, search-engine

If I go to **www.google.com** and search for something, are the listings pulled straight from the original HTML ("text-only") page load, or do the listings also account for (i.e. include) any possible front-end CSS / JavaScript stylings/adjustments?

--

Long version: Consider this basic example and followup questions:

[image: This is me Googling the word "chicken"]

1. If we were a web developer for the Wikipedia (first entry listed) and, for some reason, we changed the word "Chicken" on our page to say "Triceratops" using jQuery (within a standard `$(document).ready()`), would that listing still say "Chicken" in the title and excerpt below the title, or would it say "Triceratops"? **NOTE**: Keep in mind that it is possible to do this within `<title>` inside `<head>`, or somewhere in `<body>`.
2. Similarly, what if we were a web developer for same organization and used some CSS `display:none` or `:after` trickery to make it say "Triceratops" instead of "Chicken", what would this listing say? **NOTE**: This would probably only apply to places inside `<body>` since as far as I know, tags like `<title>` inside `<head>` are not adjustable via CSS (they are text-only, No HTML).

**Related**: [When will my site's CSS affect my search engine ranking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561420/when-will-my-sites-css-affect-my-search-engine-ranking)

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html

Comment: thx @JosephEvans, that definitely is in the right direction. Care to point out any specific part that answers my question directly? (as an answer, and then i'll mark it as such also)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Comment: thanks for the feedback @JohnConde , I think it is a bit of a 'crossover' questions between JavaScript/CSS and SEO. Though yes, perhaps primarily SEO. If you or anyone else who voted to close wants to edit it to make it better... please feel free. I'll go ahead and edit it now

Answer (score 1):

[This Webmaster blog post](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) states that the web crawler now executes Javascript and renders the page with CSS to have results look closer to what a user would experience it as.

> Today, we'll talk about our capability to render richer websites — meaning we see your content more like modern Web browsers, include the external resources, execute JavaScript and apply CSS.
>   ...
>   In order to solve this problem, we decided to try to understand pages by executing JavaScript. It’s hard to do that at the scale of the current web, but we decided that it’s worth it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this *directly* answers my question. You can see my update to my question... I feel like they might only be talking about their new 'mobile' SEO ranking algorithms... just not sure. At any rate, I'm doing some testing, and I should know for myself soon. I may not come back to this question until next week FYI

Answer (score 1):

Here is some tests on indexing after content injection via JavaScript: http://www.centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html

Using such technique described in the article you can check if content is indexed in your case.

Comment: Looks like a good article, though would be great to know what the limit is for JavaScript... 1000ms still 'works' I guess, but what about, say, 3000ms? Would be cool to know where that 'line' is. Also would be nice to see an explicit mention of CSS